# Firebase Analytics and Crashlytics answers

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

My colleague is going to install `crashlytics` in the application. Now crashlytics is a part of `firebase` and when we check the dependencies of crashlytics we can see that crashlytics requires for `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1`

```
\--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1
     +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.2
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.7
     |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.1 -> 1.4.2
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1
     |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.1 -> 1.4.2
\--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.6.1
     +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.2
     \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.1 (*)
```

The question: does it work correctly with `Firebase Analytics`? Is it not doing the same job twice? The question is happened because we have also installed `Firebase Analytics`.

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes, it works correctly with Firebase Analytics. If two or more Dependencies include references to the same sub-dependency or if the sub-dependency is also explicitly listed in your application, the sub-dependency is included only once with version set to the highest version-number referenced.

As for your second question, if one were to interpret it as to the presence of an observable overlap in functionality, then no, even-though the Firebase Analytics Dashboard displays information related to crashes, the same links back to the Crashlytics Dashboard.

Comment: Yes i know it's will work, but does it's will do twice the job ? i don't want to have 2 analytics solutions in the app that will send 2 times the http 
 request to update the 2 different solutions

Comment: Both gather different metric-sets and are different functional components. So, it would make sense for them to send separate requests.

Comment: so it's seam a little crazy that to add just crashlytics we must also include crashlytics answers because the library is dependant of it  :( maybe i miss something ?

Comment: From their documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics) , com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core doesn't need to be explicitly added as a dependency but may be an alternative if you're looking to decrease your app's apk size. All that dependency graph tells you is that Crashalytics has a dependency on the Answers Library. This may have something to do with how it used to work as part of the original Fabric SDK.